# Where to find Study Groups for Mathematics?

Tags: self-learning, education, learning

I’m doing my master’s on Optimal Transport, and I’ve been reading “Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians”. The book has been challenging, and I’ve started to wonder if there were online Study Groups for mathematics topics such as this, where people choose a book and set a data to discuss it.

Does anyone know a platform/site where people organize On-line Study Groups with the focus on Mathematics? I’ve found websites such as [Meetup](https://meetup.com), where people organize study groups, but I didn’t find anything there focused on mathematics. Perhaps a group on Slack or something like it.

Comment: Here. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Specifically, in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have finished reading the "most" part (large than 1/2) of the book, if you would like to discuss about the content of the book you can email me at fcao5@asu.edu

Comment: I've started a study group on a platform called Zulip. Let me know if you'd like to join.